# Angular dynamic component with ng-template

Tags: angular, ng-template, angular-dynamic-components

Component with `ng-template`

```js
@Component({
  template: `
    <div>Hello Component is here!</div>

    <ng-template #cmp_anchor>
      <div>Template content</div>
    </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class HelloComponent {}
```

When rendered with **ngTemplateOutlet** there is no access to ng-template

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="helloComponent"></ng-container>

    <ng-container
      [ngTemplateOutlet]="cmpTemplateRef">
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public helloComponent = HelloComponent;

  @ContentChild('cmp_anchor', {read: TemplateRef}) cmpTemplateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

Example code on: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-component-outlet-with-ng-template?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

That's indeed not possible. The `@ContentChild` in a component looks at the content inside the components tag. For instance: `<my-cmp><ng-template #cmp_anchor></ng-template></my-cmp>`, would return a template if you set the `@ContentChild` on the `MyComponent` class.

There is no direct way for accessing the `ng-template` from a component projected using the `ngComponentOutlet`. You cannot even access the `HelloComponent` instance.

You can do a private access to the `_componentRef` of the `ngComponentOutlet` instance, but that's a bit hacky. I suggest you go back to the drawing board, or rephrase your question with what greater issue you are trying to solve with your request. Anyways, to make it work, you can (but shouldn't) do the following:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div>Hello Component is here!</div>

    <ng-template #cmp_anchor>
      <div>Template content</div>
    </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @ViewChild('cmp_anchor', {read: TemplateRef})
  cmpTemplateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="helloComponent"></ng-container>

    <ng-container
      [ngTemplateOutlet]="$any(ng)?._componentRef.instance.cmpTemplateRef">
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public helloComponent = HelloComponent;

  @ViewChild(NgComponentOutlet) ng: NgComponentOutlet;
}
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-component-outlet-with-ng-template-xmj3sh)

If it's still something you think you need to do this way, you can always write your own structural directive based upon the `ngComponentOutlet` directive. From there you can expose all kind of things from whatever is passed into the outlet directive

Comment: This produces compile error in angular 9+ where ivy is used

Comment: @AleksandarPetrovic it being sort of a hack, I can imagine it does. I've added a `$any()` around the `ng` in the template. That should fix that error. Nevertheless, I don't think you should use that solution, as I said before